# AWS CloudFront OCSP stapling

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I've got a problem with CloudFront and OCSP stapling.

I expect to get OCSP stapling for every request to my site hosted on S3+CloudFront.
It is required by design.

During the research, I found [this site](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=170516) with similar question and this quote from documentation:

> When CloudFront receives a lot of HTTPS requests for the same domain, every server in the edge location soon has a response from the CA that it can "staple" to a packet in the SSL handshake

As I understand it:

- OCSP stapling works with default domain and does NOT work with custom domain until it receives some (unknown) number of requests;
- OCSP stapling turns on automatically.

I see possible but not convenient solutions here:

- Create a lambda function for 'viewer response' and use it for manual stapled response;
- Create EC2 with Nginx and use OCSP stapling provided by it (migrate from CloudFront).

Is there any easier way to force OCSP stapling for CloudFront?

Comment: No. There are couple of problems, 1. OCSP stapling in CloudFront is per edge location basis not centralized so it a request connects to a different edge location, it won't get the stapled response , 2. There is no pre-fetch if cache expires for stapled response. You can try CloudFlare: https://blog.cloudflare.com/high-reliability-ocsp-stapling/

Comment: hey, do you have any updates about that? try to understand why not have OCSP stapling when use my CNAME

Comment: Looks like there's still no way to achieve OCSP stapling on all TLS responses.

Comment: I also don't think the viewer response lambda approach would work because the TLS logic lives one layer below.